# Add elements after first and last ul in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="parent-div" id="uniqueidnumber">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<ul>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
</ul>
<!-- here opened div should end and new with same class opened -->
<p>some text</p>
<ul>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
</ul>
<!-- here div should end -->
<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

There are multiple parent-div divs and like I said in comments I need to close opened div after first `<ul>` and then open new div with same class, then after last `<ul>` close that div.
With this code I get n number (for each parent-div) of `<div class="col-xs-6"></div>` under first `<ul>` in first parent-div.

```
$('.parent-div').each(function() {
    $('.parent-div ul').first().after('</div><div class="col-xs-6">');
    $('.parent-div ul').last().after('</div>');
})
```

How can I insert needed code in each parent-div after first and last `<ul>`?

Comment: You cannot append just opening or closing tags. You need to modify your code manually.

Comment: yes, and your html code is invalid (cause of the missing closing tag) - that's a bad thing to start from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was kind of an interesting problem... but I believe this does what you want.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7875hms/2/)

```
$(".parent-div").each(function () {
    var $div1 = $(this).find(".col-xs-6");
    var $div2 = $("<div class='col-xs-6'></div>");
    var $lastUl = $div1.children("ul").last();
    var $section = $div1.children("ul").first().nextUntil($lastUl);
    var $after = $lastUl.nextAll();
    $div2.append($section);
    $div2.append($lastUl);
    $div2.insertAfter($div1);
    $after.insertAfter($div2);
});
```

---

If you wanted to split at each first level `ul`, you could use the above with recursion like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7875hms/3/)

```
$(".parent-div").each(function () {
    var $div1 = $(this).find(".col-xs-6");
    splitItUp($div1);
});
function splitItUp($div1) {
    var $div2 = $("<div class='col-xs-6'></div>");
    var $lastUl = $div1.children("ul").last();
    var $section = $div1.children("ul").first().nextUntil($lastUl);
    var $after = $lastUl.nextAll();
    $div2.append($section);
    $div2.append($lastUl);
    $div2.insertAfter($div1);
    $after.insertAfter($div2);
    if($div2.children("ul").length > 1) {
        splitItUp($div2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works with basically same approach used in my anwser (you answered earlier than me). +1

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Assuming you want to move all elements after first `ul` to a `new column`, this should work for you :

```
$('.parent-div').each(function() {
    var newDiv = $('<div></div>', {'class': 'col-xs-6'});
    var found = false;
    $('div.col-xs-6', this).children().each(function(){
        if(!found && !$(this).is('ul')) {
            return;
        } else if(!found) {
            found = true;
        } else {
            $(this).clone().appendTo(newDiv);
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    newDiv.appendTo(this);
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Pretty close, looks like you'll want to add something to make sure that the stuff after the last `ul` doesn't get added to the second `col-xs-6`. ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/cw4udbo5/))

Comment: @smerny Yes, also, nextUntil doesn't unclude the last ul element in the new col-xs-6 :)

Comment: That's why I appended it specifically.

Comment: @smerny Oh yes! Sorry, did not see that line.

Comment: Actually, sorry but this isn't really as close as I thought. All it is doing is appending everything after the first ul (including stuff after the last) to the new div and doing a lot of unnecessary DOM manipulation in the process. The entire each() block could be replaced with `$('div.col-xs-6', this).children('ul').first().nextAll().appendTo(newDiv);` for the same result with only 2 DOM manipulation instead of 2*n where n is the number of elements after the first ul.